# Keep looping until ram is full then pause and continue the loop once it get free again

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, while-loop, sh

I have to run a command on many files which I do by bash looping and an ampersand at the end of each command so files run in parallel. Yet I don't want to consume all the ram on the server in case where I have 100 or such files. Is there a way to keep the loop going on until ram usage exceed certain threshold and at this point the loop pauses and once ram is free again then continue looping to next files ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. Use the `free` command to determine the RAM usage. Then compare the current usage to your threshold. Wrap the condition of the loop into a function to make it a bit more readable:

```
ramAboveThreshold() {
   local threshold=6000000000 # threshold in bytes (6 GB)
   local used="$(free -b | awk 'NR == 2 {print $2}')"
   (( used > threshold ))
}
```

Inside your old loop, place another loop that waits for the RAM usage to drop under your threshold:

```
for i in myFiles/*; do
    while ramAboveThreshold; do
        sleep 5
    done
    myCommand "$i" &
done
```

`free` does not only print the used RAM, but also the free and total RAM, so the script could be altered to have a a threshold like »*at least n bytes free*« or even »*less than 60% used*«.

Comment: I changed it a little bit to match my style in coding and need your feedback. I recalculate the used inside the while loop to skip the function like this
while $used > $threshold; do
sleep 5
used="$(free -b | awk 'NR == 2 {print $2}')"
done

Comment: You have to put arithmetic expression and checks in double parenthesis: `while (( $used > $threshold ))`.

Comment: On my system, the second field of the second line of "free -b" is the total amount of ram. Clearly, installed ram never changes. But also the free amount of ram is not a good indication, because the kernel tends to use up most of the available ram. Perhaps a good value to look at is free+buffers.